# Syntax error using the WITH clause

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to setup a CTE table with a series of quarterly dates.
The query returns [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "values" Position: 38

```
with q(qqyy, firstday, lastday) as (
values
('Q4_10', '09-30-2010', '12-31-2010'),
('Q1_11', '12-31-2010', '03-31-2011'),
('Q2_11', '03-31-2011', '06/30/2011'),
('Q3_11', '06/30/2011', '09/30/2011'),
('Q4_11', '09/30/2011', '12/31/2011'),
('Q1_12', '12/31/2011', '03/31/2012'),
('Q2_12', '03/31/2012', '06/30/2012'),
('Q3_12', '06/30/2012', '09/30/2012'),
('Q4_12', '09/30/2012', '12/31/2012'),
('Q1_13', '12/31/2012', '03/31/2013'),
('Q2_13', '03/31/2013', '06/30/2013'),
('Q3_13', '06/30/2013', '09/30/2013'),
('Q4_13', '09/30/2013', '12/31/2013'),
('Q1_14', '12/31/2013', '03/31/2014'),
('Q2_14', '03/31/2014', '06/30/2014'),
('Q3_14', '06/30/2014', '09/30/2014'),
('Q4_14', '09/30/2014', '12/31/2014'),
('Q1_15', '12/31/2014', '03/31/2015'),
('Q2_15', '03/31/2015', '06/30/2015'),
('Q3_15', '06/30/2015', '09/30/2015'),
('Q4_15', '09/30/2015', '12/31/2015'),
('Q1_16', '12/31/2015', '03/31/2016'),
('Q2_16', '03/31/2016', '06/30/2016'),
('Q3_16', '06/30/2016', '09/30/2016'),
('Q4_16', '09/30/2016', '12/31/2016')
  )

SELECT q.qqyy, cobrand_id, sum(calc)
into   temp_08.cmg_calc
from temp_08.cmg s 
join q on 
s.transaction_date >= q.firstday 
and s.transaction_date <= q.lastday
GROUP BY q.qqyy, cobrand_id;
```

It appears that the above query is getting stuck on "values" due to Redshift using an older version of postgresql (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html).  But for some reason the below query that also uses "values" works fine.  Any idea how I can get the above query to work using redshift?

```
 create table temp_08.cmgquarters (
quarter_col text
  , date_from   date
  , date_to     date
);


 insert into temp_08.cmgquarters
   values
('Q4_10', '09-30-2010', '12-31-2010'),
('Q1_11', '12-31-2010', '03-31-2011'),
('Q2_11', '03-31-2011', '06/30/2011'),
('Q3_11', '06/30/2011', '09/30/2011'),
('Q4_11', '09/30/2011', '12/31/2011'),
('Q1_12', '12/31/2011', '03/31/2012'),
('Q2_12', '03/31/2012', '06/30/2012'),
('Q3_12', '06/30/2012', '09/30/2012'),
('Q4_12', '09/30/2012', '12/31/2012'),
('Q1_13', '12/31/2012', '03/31/2013'),
('Q2_13', '03/31/2013', '06/30/2013'),
('Q3_13', '06/30/2013', '09/30/2013'),
('Q4_13', '09/30/2013', '12/31/2013'),
('Q1_14', '12/31/2013', '03/31/2014'),
('Q2_14', '03/31/2014', '06/30/2014'),
('Q3_14', '06/30/2014', '09/30/2014'),
('Q4_14', '09/30/2014', '12/31/2014'),
('Q1_15', '12/31/2014', '03/31/2015'),
('Q2_15', '03/31/2015', '06/30/2015'),
('Q3_15', '06/30/2015', '09/30/2015'),
('Q4_15', '09/30/2015', '12/31/2015'),
('Q1_16', '12/31/2015', '03/31/2016'),
('Q2_16', '03/31/2016', '06/30/2016'),
('Q3_16', '06/30/2016', '09/30/2016'),
('Q4_16', '09/30/2016', '12/31/2016');
```

Comment: apart from the invalid date literals that should work.

Comment: http://rextester.com/NYIW15367

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - when I run the script in your link, it seems to work fine.  But when I run the script in my IDE, I get the same error: [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "values" Position: 41.  For what it's worth, I'm using the DataGrip IDE from JetBrains which uses PostgreSQL.  Any  thoughts?

Comment: Maybe your IDE tries to be too smart and doesn't know about common table expressions. Does it work with `psql`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I can only use postgresql.  Any idea of a workaround/why this may stumble?  Thank you kindly for your help.

Comment: @ZJAY If this might be *multi-statement-SQL* you could replace the CTE with a simple temp db (or a table variable if supported in postgressql). Create the table (with typed columns!), fill it with your values, use it in your  main statement and drop it at the end... (temp tables probably disappear on their own when out of scope...)

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "*I can only use postgresql*". `psql` is the default command line client for Postgres - you should try you query using that instead of your current IDE to make sure it's not an issue with the tool you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I reran your query with a separate IDE (SQL workbench) and got the same error around "values."  By way of reference, both IDEs use the following: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1115.  Any other suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: You are not using Postgres, you are using Redshift  (which is based on a **really** old and outdated version of Postgres). According to the [Redshift manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html) the `values()` clause as a constant table is not supported

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Given your clear command of postgres, do you know of a workaround for values() that would work on the older redshift postgres.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please do not add the `postgresql` tag. Amazon Redshift is different enough from Postgres so that the `postgresql` tag is misleading (which the comments to your question clearly show)

Comment: Understood.  Any idea of what I could use instead of   values().  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Redshift not supporting the `values()` as a "table replacement" you need to re-write that as a `union`:

```
with q(qqyy, firstday, lastday) as (
  select 'Q4_10', '09-30-2010', '12-31-2010' union all
  select 'Q1_11', '12-31-2010', '03-31-2011' union all
  ....
)
SELECT ...;
```

you should however user proper DATE literals:

```
with q(qqyy, firstday, lastday) as (
  select 'Q4_10', DATE '2010-09-30', DATE '2010-12-31' union all
  select 'Q1_11', DATE '2010-12-31', DATE '2011-03-31' union all
  ....
)
SELECT ...;
```

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately this solution still returns  [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "values" Position: 37

Comment: @ZJAY: sorry, copy & paste error. The `values` must be removed completely of course

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Postgres well enough, but with SQL-Server you cannot use the `VALUES` like a table directly. You must use parenthesis around and provide a table alias with column names to define the derived table.

This would be something like this:

```
with q as (
select * from
(
    values
    ('Q4_10', '09-30-2010', '12-31-2010'),
    ('Q1_11', '12-31-2010', '03-31-2011'),
    ('Q2_11', '03-31-2011', '06/30/2011'),
    ('Q3_11', '06/30/2011', '09/30/2011'),
    ('Q4_11', '09/30/2011', '12/31/2011'),
    ('Q1_12', '12/31/2011', '03/31/2012'),
    ('Q2_12', '03/31/2012', '06/30/2012'),
    ('Q3_12', '06/30/2012', '09/30/2012'),
    ('Q4_12', '09/30/2012', '12/31/2012'),
    ('Q1_13', '12/31/2012', '03/31/2013'),
    ('Q2_13', '03/31/2013', '06/30/2013'),
    ('Q3_13', '06/30/2013', '09/30/2013'),
    ('Q4_13', '09/30/2013', '12/31/2013'),
    ('Q1_14', '12/31/2013', '03/31/2014'),
    ('Q2_14', '03/31/2014', '06/30/2014'),
    ('Q3_14', '06/30/2014', '09/30/2014'),
    ('Q4_14', '09/30/2014', '12/31/2014'),
    ('Q1_15', '12/31/2014', '03/31/2015'),
    ('Q2_15', '03/31/2015', '06/30/2015'),
    ('Q3_15', '06/30/2015', '09/30/2015'),
    ('Q4_15', '09/30/2015', '12/31/2015'),
    ('Q1_16', '12/31/2015', '03/31/2016'),
    ('Q2_16', '03/31/2016', '06/30/2016'),
    ('Q3_16', '06/30/2016', '09/30/2016'),
    ('Q4_16', '09/30/2016', '12/31/2016')
  ) AS tbl(qqyy, firstday, lastday)
)
SELECT *
from q
```

### Attention

You are in high danger!

- You are using culture dependant date formats. This might work in your system, but break on another one...
- Further more, your are not even consistent!
- Your `VALUES` provide your date values as string.

In SQL-Server I'd suggest to use ISO8601, unseparated or - my favourite - ODBC. But I'm sure there are culture independent formats for literal dates in Postgres too.

And I would suggest to let the CTE come back with typed values or use a temp table with typed columns.

Comment: In Postgres you _can_ use `values` like that.

Comment: And in Postgres it's better to use ANSI date literals, e.g. `date '2016-12-31'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thx again, I was sure, that each RDBMS has a *best* literal date format. `2016-12-31` seems to be quite close to `ISO 8601` anyway, but is quite far away from the (mixed) formats provided above...

Comment: That's how a date literal is defined by the SQL standard - theoretically every DBMS should honour that (but Microsoft never really cared about the standard)

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name.  What's the downside of using the dates as I used above?

Comment: @ZJAY: they will fail with different locales (they do on my computer)

Comment: @ZJAY You are relying on implicit conversion of your string to a date type. It is depending on your system's culture wheter a string is taken as `dd/mm/yyyy` or as `mm/dd/yyyy`. It is especially odd wiht formats, where the year has just two digits ...